# How to bind a model to an option's value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In Angular 1.2.11, given a controller with:

```
$scope.produce = { 'apples' : [{ 'variety' : 'granny smith', 'price': 2.00}] }
```

And a view with

```
<select ng-model='fruits'>
  <option value="0">More Fruits...</option>
  <option ng-repeat="p.apple for p in produce" value="p">{{ p.variety }}</option>
</select>
```

How can I bind 'p' to the value attribute? If I try as above the model is bound as a JSON string, not as the model itself (as it would be if I were able to use ng-options).

I'm working around this now by using an ng-change function that uses the value bound to `fruits` as a lookup in `$scope.produce`, but this seems like a workaround rather than a solution.

**EDIT:** Sorry I wasn't more clear about this: I need to be able to hard code 1+ options into the select list, so using ng-options is not a solution.

Here are some fiddles to help illustrate my problem:

** [Using ng-options](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ5QF/7/) ** 
ng-options allows for one  element that it uses for creating a default option for use as a label. Two problems with this: if I try to use that `<option>` for its intended purpose I can't add a second option to the select. On the other hand, if I just try to add one `<option>` element, it gets placed at the top of the `<select>` list. No good.

** [Using ng-repeat](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ5QF/6/) ** 
I'm unable to bind the model to the `value` attribute of the `<option>` element. Instead, the value is stringified JSON, which is not bindable.

Comment: Be careful about creating options like this. There are known problems. That's why the dev team came up with `ng-options`. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select I'm probably not going to even use the `select` element anymore, myself. I prefer making my own.

Comment: I don't think your data structure makes sense - is `produce` supposed to be an array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-options:

```
<select ng-model='fruits' ng-options="thisFruit.variety in apples">
</select>
```

If you need to have an option selected as a default (your "More Fruits" option) then you need to add that to the data before it gets to the repeater, and also set your model $scope.fruits = 0 to make that selection selected by default.